# Split Names in column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm fairly new to python and working with a DataFrame in pandas & numpy from The Movie Database. One of the columns notes the main cast of each movie separated by the pipe symbol (|). I'm trying to find a way to split each individual cast member and list it in its own row with the movie title. I've attached a snippet below of the results I get.

```
tmdb_data = pd.read_csv('tmdb-movies.csv')
cast_split = tmdb_data[['original_title', 'cast']]
df = pd.DataFrame(cast_split)
df.head()
```

[Movie Title & Cast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GajZ2.png)

**Expected Output:**

```
    original_title                 cast
0  Jursassic World           Chris Patt
1  Jursassic World  Bryce Dallas Howard
2  Jursassic World          Irrfan Khan
```

Comment: What's the problem? If you want to split then use `split`.

Comment: can you show us your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) + [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) + [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) + [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rename.html) + [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for new `Series` and then [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

---

```
tmdb_data = pd.DataFrame({'movie':['Jursassic World', 'Insurgent'], 
                           'cast':['Chris Patt|Bryce Dallas Howard|Irrfan Khan', 
                                   'Shailene Woodley|Theo James']}, 
                         columns=['movie', 'cast'])


print (tmdb_data)
             movie                                        cast
0  Jursassic World  Chris Patt|Bryce Dallas Howard|Irrfan Khan
1        Insurgent                 Shailene Woodley|Theo James

df1 = (tmdb_data.join(tmdb_data.pop('cast').str.split('|', expand=True)
                               .stack()
                               .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
                               .rename('cast'))
                               .reset_index(drop=True))

print (df1)

             movie                 cast
0  Jursassic World           Chris Patt
1  Jursassic World  Bryce Dallas Howard
2  Jursassic World          Irrfan Khan
3        Insurgent     Shailene Woodley
4        Insurgent           Theo James
```

Answer (score 1):

First cast as a list (pardon the pun!), then rebuild dataframe via `numpy`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['Jursassic World', 'Chris Patt|Bryce Dallas Howard']], columns=['movie', 'cast'])

df.cast = df.cast.str.split('|')

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'movie': np.repeat(df.movie.values, df.cast.str.len()),
                    'cast': np.concatenate(df.cast.values)})

#                   cast            movie
# 0           Chris Patt  Jursassic World
# 1  Bryce Dallas Howard  Jursassic World
```